# Composite cell event Handling

Tags: gwt, grid, gxt, uibinder

I'm using a composite cell in a grid which has two buttons.I want to handle the click events on both the buttons seperately.Is it possible?
 please explain in detail how to handle these events seperately.

I'm attaching my composite cell code with the buttons for the reference.

```
private CompositeCell<FilterInfo> createCompositeCell(){

HasCell<FilterInfo, String> button1= new HasCell<FilterInfo, String>() {

  public Cell<String> getCell() {
    return new TextCell();
  }

  public FieldUpdater<FilterInfo, String> getFieldUpdater() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }

  public String getValue(FilterInfo object) {
    return "button 1";
  }};

  HasCell<FilterInfo, String> button2= new HasCell<FilterInfo,String>(){

    public Cell<String> getCell() {
      return new ButtonCell();
    }

    public FieldUpdater<FilterInfo, String> getFieldUpdater() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return null;
    }

    public String getValue(FilterInfo object) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return "button 2";
    }
  };

  List<HasCell<FilterInfo, ?>> cells = new ArrayList<HasCell<FilterInfo, ?>>();
  cells.add(button1);
  cells.add(button2);

  CompositeCell<FilterInfo> compositeCell = new CompositeCell<FilterInfo>(cells);

  return compositeCell;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You handle click event in `FieldUpdater` of each button.

Here is minimal working example:

```
package com.adam.test.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gwt.cell.client.ButtonCell;
import com.google.gwt.cell.client.CompositeCell;
import com.google.gwt.cell.client.FieldUpdater;
import com.google.gwt.cell.client.HasCell;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellList;
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.Column;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class Test implements EntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        CompositeCell<FilterInfo> compositeCell = createCompositeCell();
        CellList<FilterInfo> list = new CellList<FilterInfo>(compositeCell);

        List<FilterInfo> values = new ArrayList<FilterInfo>();
        values.add(new FilterInfo());
        values.add(new FilterInfo());
        values.add(new FilterInfo());
        list.setRowData(values);

        RootPanel.get().add(list);
    }

    private CompositeCell<FilterInfo> createCompositeCell() {
        Column<FilterInfo, String> button1Column = new Column<FilterInfo, String>(new ButtonCell()) {
            @Override
            public String getValue(FilterInfo object) {
                return "Button 1";
            }
        };
        button1Column.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<FilterInfo, String>() {
            @Override
            public void update(int index, FilterInfo object, String value) {
                Window.alert("Button 1 clicked!");
            }
        });

        Column<FilterInfo, String> button2Column = new Column<FilterInfo, String>(new ButtonCell()) {
            @Override
            public String getValue(FilterInfo object) {
                return "Button 2";
            }
        };
        button2Column.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<FilterInfo, String>() {
            @Override
            public void update(int index, FilterInfo object, String value) {
                Window.alert("Button 2 clicked!");
            }
        });

        ArrayList<HasCell<FilterInfo, ?>> compositeColumns = new ArrayList<HasCell<FilterInfo, ?>>();
        compositeColumns.add(button1Column);
        compositeColumns.add(button2Column);

        return new CompositeCell<FilterInfo>(compositeColumns);
    }

    private class FilterInfo {}
}
```

Comment: Please can anyone give an example code wise with the handlers

Comment: I've updated code in my answer. Now it is working example code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create the custom cell and override the `onBrowserEvent` and `render` methods.  Handle the click event in the `onBrowserEvent` method.

Refer http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells.html